# Count the number of emails each day in Outlook 2003?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

This is for a little pet project of mine.

I want to write a program that does some email analytics and tells you the number of emails coming in and out each day, as well as your percentages. Really, all I need to do to kick this off is write a .Net app that can talk with Outlook and count the number of messages received and sent for give dates.

Before I got too deep into this, I figured I'd poll the group and see if there is a particular approach I should follow when starting something like this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just FYI, (not to discourage you) Xobni offers this product free of charge.  http://www.xobni.com/

Comment: No not at all man. I'm looking into this right now. I did some research before and didn't come across anything so this link is interesting indeed. No need to re-invent the wheel in this case (even if that is fun sometimes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an Outlook Add-in which will do the job for you. its very easy to write an Add in using Visual Studio Tools for Office ([VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx)).

Comment: I will give this answer to you because ultimately, this is where I'd need to start and how I'd need to do it. For my purposes, xobni really did the trick so I didn't have to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: I can help you in writing the addin. Let me know if you face any difficulty.